# Is Luke 21:28 alluding to Job 10:14-17?

Tags: luke, job, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible

> [Luk 21:28 ESV] (28) Now when these things begin to take place, **straighten up and raise your heads**, because your redemption is drawing near."
>
> [Job 10:14-17 ESV] (14) If I sin, you watch me and do not acquit me of my iniquity. (15) If I am guilty, woe to me! If I am in the right, **I cannot lift up my head**, for I am filled with disgrace and look on my affliction. (16) **And were my head lifted up, you would hunt me like a lion and again work wonders against me**. (17) You **renew your witnesses against me** and **increase your vexation** toward me; **you bring fresh troops against me**.

My thought is that they must be ready, have a clear conscience, etc. And if not, he will bring fresh troops against them.

Answer (score 1):

Since lifting up the head (Psalms 110:7) or the horn (1 Samuel 2:10), and conversely a falling face (Genesis 4:6) aren't uncommon idioms, I don't think that there must be a specific passage that Luke is alluding to here, much less to Job, in which bringing troops, the only parallel I see to Luke, comes after lifting up the head, is only one in a list of afflictions, and moreover might not have even been interpreted as troops in the Septuagint (NETS: "and brought trials on me" instead of troops).

However, the case of Psalms 110:7 deserves more attention. Since this psalm is interpreted in the New Testament with messianic overtones (Luke uses it in 20:42), it could have been a source for Luke's description of Jerusalem's desolation.

> He will execute judgment among the nations,
>       filling them with corpses;
>   he will shatter heads
>       over the wide earth.
>    He will drink from the stream by the path;
>       therefore he will lift up his head. (Psalms 110:6-7, NRSV)

Like this psalm, Luke describes a great war, and concludes the description with the expression "raise your heads." If Luke is making an allusion to a specific passage, I think this would be the one. However, both this psalm and Luke both make heavy use of imagery here, and very little of it overlaps. There is lots of room for symbolic interpretation of these verses, but I don't see Luke taking advantage of it. The psalm also seems to be about the destruction of the nations, while Luke is about the nations destroying Jerusalem. For those reasons I would hesitate to say for sure that Luke is alluding to this passage rather than just using the same idiom.